# Processing multidimensional lists with nested for loops in python?

Tags: python, nuke

I am writing code for Nuke - The foundry.. I have been banging my head for 3 hours now.. looking up on google but without success
What i am trying to do is basically create 2 dimensional list and populate it with something..
In my case i want to populate the list with  `db = [['nodeName1', 'inputnName1'], ['nodeName2', 'imputName2'], etc...]`

I create the list with db = `[[None for x in range(2)] for y in range (nMasks)]` - where nMasks is a variable of how many rows there should be in "db"

now i want to populate the list with my variables somehow.. i tried this:

```
for i in range(len(db)): #row
    for j in range(len(db[i])): #element
        for n in nuke.selectedNodes():
            if j == 0:
                db[i][j] = n #populate list with node
            if j != 0:
                db[i][j] = 'a' #for now it's just an a and nothing more but ill have to change this to an actual nodeName
```

This gives me different result of what i want - 
when i do:

```
print db[0][0]['name'].value()
print db[0][1]

print db[1][0]['name'].value()
print db[1][1]
```

i get result:

## Result:

Node1
a
Node1
a

and i want it to look like:

## Result:

Node1
a
Node2
a

note: maybe there is even more elegant solution for this?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are trying to do, but this structure looks odd. There's a high likelyhood a different structure (such as a `dictionary`) would be better suited. Also because of how you structured your nested loops, you will always have the exact same node at the 0 position `db[x][0]`

Comment: @UnholySheep how do you do it so i get result 2 here? thanks

Comment: As I said I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve. I guess putting `for n in nuke.selectedNodes():` as the outermost loop might give you your desired results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally populate a list by appending values to it. This way you don't need to know in advance the size of the list. What it seems that you are trying to do from your desired output, is to get the `selectedNodes` into a 2D array `db`. It seems like `db[i][0]` should be be `nuke.selectedNodes()[i]` while `db[i][1]` should be a string. I don't really understand what your `nMasks` has to do with the number of selected nodes but, if your intention was to get all the selected nodes, it seems that the following would be more natural to get the 2D list that you want

```
sn = nuke.selectedNodes()
db = 
for n in nuke.selectedNodes():
    db.append([n,'a'])
```

---

### edit

There are many, many ways to get the same list. For instance, you could use list comprehension to sum it up into a single line

```
db = [[n,'a'] for n in nuke.selectedNodes()]
```

But if you want to use nested loops like in your question's code, you could do it like this

```
db = [[None for x in range(2)] for y in range (nMasks)]
for i in range(len(db)):
    for j in range(len(db[0])):
        if j == 0:
            db[i][j] = nuke.selectedNodes()[i] #populate list with node
        else:
            db[i][j] = 'a'
```

Comment: Thanks that's it... though what would it look like if you wanted to do it with nested loops as i tried initially? (my nMasks is just a variable that defines the size - i am filtering some nodes)